# Package conflict in `subfig` and `ifthen`

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats, incompatibility

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[\ifthenelse{1>0}{foo}{bar}]{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Error msg:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \sf@captionlist.
>
> l.6 ...ifthenelse{1>0}{foo}{bar}]{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}

`\subfloat[][\ifthenelse{1>0}{foo}{bar}]{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}` works well, if there is need to display a listoffigure in ones document. However, if I do need the listoffigure, can someone explain how this conflict occor and how to avoid it, for me?

Comment: `subfig` is considered deprecated. The replacement package for subfloats is `subcaption`. You will likely run into less trouble if your use the latter instead of the former.

Comment: @Jubobs Oh really? So the path is `subfigure` to `subfig` to `subcaption`?

Comment: @Jubobs `subfig` is *not* deprecated. It has problems with `hyperref`, but with document classes which are incompatible with `caption` (`revtex4-1`, to mention one), it's the only package providing for subfloat captioning, because it allows the `caption=false` loading option for avoiding to load also `caption`. This said, probably the `caption`–`subcaption` pair is better.

Comment: @egreg I believe you, but I think I've read claims that `subfig` is deprecated/obsolete in several places on the site. I'll try to find them so we can tell the truth about `subfig`.

Comment: The German version of `l2tabu` states (wrongly) that `subfig` is incompatible with `caption`. This is not true, as `subfig` can work both with and without `caption`. I guess this is the source for the “deprecation”; however, while I believe that `subcaption` is better than `subfig`, this package can find its usage, as I told before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put `\ifthenelse` in the optional argument of `\subfloat` because of how both commands work. Adding `\protect` in front of `\ifthenelse` might seem a good workaround, but it doesn't work (see output later).

If you need conditionals in the optional argument to `\subfloat`, you can use the `etoolbox` ones; for instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[\ifnumcomp{1}{>}{0}{foo}{bar}]{\rule{3cm}{3cm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

There are many of them, see section 3.6 in the documentation.

[image]

---

Here's the output with your code after adding `\protect` in front of `\ifthenelse`: the compilation error vanishes, but the output is wrong.

[image]

Comment: I searched 'LaTeX fragile command' for about one hour, after I have seen your answer. Definitely, your answer is great, as I learn a lot from it. However, as searching result said, adding `\protect` to a fragile command can avoid problems it causes. I wonder, why `\protect` doesn't work in this case? Is there something different than the situation when we talk about a fragile command? Further more, be lower level, is `\ifthenelse` a fragile command? Anyway, thank you so much for the existing answer.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, `\ifthenelse` is fragile; however `\protect` doesn't work in this case because `\subfloat` wants to see the “final” text in its optional argument; with `\protect` the `\ifthenelse` command is executed at the wrong time.

Comment: so... `\protect` does not cover every situations that a fragile command could cause, which means 'LaTeX fragile command' is an unavoidable devil (if we only have the shotgun named `\protect`)? Can you introduce me some more powerful weapon, submachine gun, missile or even n-bomb?

Comment: @Shadow In most “controlled” situations, `\protect` works: section titles, captions and other *moving arguments*. But `\ifthenelse` is a wild beast, you know.

Comment: Copy that. Thank you for these pieces of explaination.